# Updating an html page using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am learning ajax stuff. And I have this task that just like some stackoverflow.com where we can add comments just by hitting Add comment button and the comment appears right there without refreshing, I have a page where user will be asked to enter a name and the name must appear added just like described before. I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#add-tournament").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    /*var password = $("#password").val();
    var country_code = $("#country_code").val();
    var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();*/
    $.ajax({
      url: '/home/',
      method: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({name: name}),
      success: function() {
        /*console.log(arguments)*/

      },
      error: function() {
        console.log(arguments)
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

What should I put under success function?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at it yourself first., then come back to us with any bugs your encounter while trying. We won't write your code for you.

Comment: @TarynEast Maybe I tried but deleted the code! I shouldn't have done that!

Comment: Give it another go... we'll wait :D use ObsidianAge's example to help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you **want** to happen, but `success` needs to have a **[function parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)**, which correlates to the data returned from the request:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

From here you can go on to display it back to the page with something like:

```
success: function(data) {
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = data;
}
```

Note that while only the first parameter is required, there are three parameters on `success`:

- `data`: The response from the request
- `textStatus`: The success status code
- `jqXHR`: The response object

And three on `error`:

- `jqXHR`: The response object
- `textStatus`: The error status code
- `errorThrown`: The type of error

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `success` section implies that the server which have already received your `/home` request where the server could send any relevant data to you (if necessary).

Generally speaking, the `success` section will be **What you are going to do next?**

```
success: function(data) {
//the data is sent by the server

//you can either noticing the user for the success submittion
Alert("Success");

//or may be showing the relevant data to user 
Alert("Mr/Ms " + name + ", you still have " + data);
}
```

Hope this help